# PHP is splitting long request query parameter

Tags: php, request, query-string

I created a php script that gets a web page url as a parameter like this. `http://example.com index.php file`

```
<?php 
$url = $_REQUEST["url"];

echo $url;
```

request is like this

```
http://example.com?url=http://myproxyapi.com/api?request=Get&format=image/png&width=20&height=20
```

this request writes screen this:

```
http://myproxyapi.com/api?request=Get
```

actually it shoulr write:

```
http://myproxyapi.com/api?request=Get&format=image/png&width=20&height=20
```

if I get this url, I will split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL is not valid:

```
http://example.com?url=http://myproxyapi.com/api?request=Get&format=image/png&width=20&height=20
```

You have to escape characters inside the query part of an url, so chars like `:/?`.

php offers the function [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for this:

```
sprintf('http://example.com?url=%s', 
        urlencode('http://myproxyapi.com/api?request=Get&format=image/png&width=20&height=20'));
```

Comment: ideally you would put your parameters in an array and use http_build_query which will generate a properly formatted query string. Edit: much like the browser, I read the url as if it was multiple key/values in the query string. A single query string item, url encode is perfectly fine.